# NIFI -- How to access the custom variable from updateattributes to groovy script

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a custom variable in Updatedate processor( state = success), now I want to access those variable in my groovy script which is in invokescriptor processor.

```
def status= flowFile.getAttribute('status')
```

i tried below mentioned both syntax as well

Attempt 1:

```
   if( status.equals("success")){
   //
```

Attempt 2:

```
  if(status == "success"){

  }
```

the above 2 attempts
`flowFile.getAttribute('status')`  returnning `null` value.

Please correct my mistake!

Comment: What Updatedate processor? And I noted that names are different: `state` and `status`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have this attribut in your flowfile :
key: state
value: success

Then you can get this attribut this way:

```
def status= flowFile.getAttribute("state")
```

if you have a null value, maybe your attribut do not exist at all ?
to verify follow the process :

1- pause your groovyscript processor
2- make a flowfile
3- inspect the flowfile attribut for state attribut inside your queue